# Basic Modular Exponentiation question

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, cryptography

I just know this rule :***ab mod n = [(a mod n)(b mod n)] mod n.***
How can it be proved that the following rule is true ?

```
x^7 mod n = {(x^4 mod n)(x^2 mod n)(x^1 mod n)} mod n
```

Comment: If only they would bother to teach congruences.... Sigh.

Comment: what do you mean ?

Comment: Sorry. Not your fault. A pet peeve of mine. Why somebody decided that computer science majors should not be taught any algebra.

Comment: Are you familiar with congruences? i.e $\ a\equiv b\pmod n\iff n\mid a-b\ \ $

Comment: @ Bill Dubuque I know  a≡b(mod n)⟺n∣a−b  ! I'm just puzzling about ...
 
{ (a mod n)[(b mod n)(c mod n) mod n ] } mod n == (a mod n)(b mod n)(c mod n) mod n ???

Comment: @ Jyrki Lahtonen @ Bill Dubuque  Is there any book that you could recommend to me for solving this problem ??

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea of **congruences** is to say that one number is **equivalent** to another by a **relation**. Numbers that are equivalent are said to belong to the same **equivalence class**.

In the case of mod, the equivalence relation is *"leave the same remainder when divided by n"*. So if we consider for example 22 and 48 mod 13, they both leave remainder 9. $22=13+9$, and $48=3.13+9$, and so 22 and 48 belong to the equivalence class of mod13. We write $22\equiv48 \mod 13$. We usually simplify the right hand  number and write $22\equiv9\mod13$.

This allows us to express general numbers in terms of the **moduli** (13 from the example just given), and a remainder.

In your example, the moduli is $n$, and we can write $a$ and $b$ as:

- $a=jn+x$
- $b=kn+y$

$a\equiv x \mod n$, and $b\equiv y \mod n $.

$ab=(jn+x)(kn+y)=jkn^2+n(jy+kx)+xy = n(jkn+jy+kx)+xy$. The remainder when divided by n is therefore $xy$, and we write $ab\equiv xy \mod n$, and as this the same as $(a \mod n)(b \mod n) \mod n $, we have proved your result.

To prove the $x^7$ result, use $x^7=x^4x^3$ and apply the theorem, and then reapply the theorem to $x^3=x^2x$.

Comment: I can't really understand your explanation. 
 Does
abc mod n = { [(a mod n)(b mod n)] mod n * (c mod n) } mod n  equals to abc mod n = [ (a mod n)(b mod n) (c mod n) ]mod n ??

Comment: for example 1243 mod 713 = {(1232 mod 713) · (128 mod 713) · (122 mod 713) · (12 mod 713)} mod 713

Comment: abc mod n == (a mod n) (bc mod n) mod n == (a mod n)(b mod n)(c mod n) mod n

Comment: Why? is it  following that "abc mod n == (a mod n) (bc mod n) mod n =={ (a mod n)[(b mod n)(c mod n) mod n ] } mod n" ?

Comment: bc mod n can be expanded like ab mod n, and x mod n mod n = x mod n

Comment: { (a mod n)[(b mod n)(c mod n) mod n ] } mod n == (a mod n)(b mod n)(c mod n) mod n  ???

Comment: @ Jon Mark Perry  Is there any book that you could recommend to me for solving this problem ??

Comment: gauss http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Friedrich_Gauss invented modular arithmetic : http://www.amazon.com/Disquisitiones-Arithmeticae-Carl-Gauss/dp/0300094736